# Iterate over two nested 2D lists where list2 has list1's row numbers

Tags: python, list, loops

I'm new to Python. So I want to get this done with loops without using some fancy stuff like generators. I have two 2D arrays, one integer array and the other string array like this:

1. Integer 2D list:

   Here, dataset2d[0][0] is number of rows in the table, dataset[0][1] is number of columns. So the below 2D list has 6 rows and 4 columns

   ```
   dataset2d = [
       [6, 4],
       [0, 0, 0, 1],
       [1, 0, 2, 0],
       [2, 2, 0, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 1],
       [1, 0, 2, 1]
   ]
   ```
2. String 2D list:

   ```
   partition2d = [
       ['A', '1', '2', '4'],
       ['B', '3', '5'],
       ['C', '6']
   ]
   ```

   `partition[*][0]` i.e first column is a label. For group A, 1,2 and 4 are the row numbers that I need to pick up from dataset2d and apply a formula. So it means I will read 1, go to row 1 in `dataset2d` and read the first column value i.e `dataset2d[1][0]`, then I will read 2 from `partition2d`, go to row 2 of dataset 2d and read the first column i.e `dataset2d[2][0]`. Similarly next one I'll read `dataset2d[4][0]`.

   Then I will do some calculations, get a value and store it in a 2D list, then go to the next column in dataset2d for those rows. So in this example, next column values read would be `dataset2d[1][1]`, `dataset2d[2][1]`, `dataset2d[4][1]`. And again do some calculation and get one value for that column, store it. I'll do this until I reach the last column of `dataset2d`.

   The next row in `partition2d` is `[B, 3, 5]`. So I'll start with `dataset2d[3][0]`, `dataset2d[5][0]`. Get a value for that column be a formula. Then real `dataset2d [3][1]`, `dataset2d[5][1]` etc. until I reach last column. I do this until all rows in partition2d are read.

What I tried:

```
 for partitionRow in partition2d:
        for partitionCol in partitionRow:
                for colDataset in dataset2d:
                     print dataset2d[partitionCol][colDataset]
```

What problem I'm facing:

1. partition2d is a string array where I need to skip the first column which has characters like A,B,C.
2. I want to iterate in dataset2d column wise only over the row numbers given in partition2d. So the colDataset should increment only after I'm done with that column.

Update1:

I'm reading the contents from a text file, and the data in 2D lists can vary, depending on file content and size, but the structure of file1 i.e dataset2d and file2 i.e partition2d will be the same.

Update2: Since Eric asked about how the output should look like.

```
 0.842322 0.94322 0.34232 0.900009    (For A)
 0.642322 0.44322 0.24232 0.800009    (For B)
```

This is just an example and the numbers are randomly typed by me.
So the first number 0.842322 is the result of applying the formula to column 0 of dataset2d i.e dataset2d[parttionCol][0] for group A having considered rows 1,2,4.

The second number, 0.94322 is the result of applying formula to column 1 of dataset2d i.e dataset2d[partitionCol][1] for group A having considered rows 1,2 4.

The third number, 0.34232  is the result of applying formula to column 2 of dataset2d i.e dataset2d[partitionCol][2] for group A having considered rows 1,2 4. Similarly we get 0.900009.

The first number in second row, i.e 0.642322 is the result of applying the formula to column 0 of dataset2d i.e dataset2d[parttionCol][0] for group B having considered rows 3,5. And so on.

Comment: "I'm new to Python. So I want to get this done with loops without using some fancy stuff like generators". I think it should be the opposite, _since_ you are new to Python, then you _should_ use "Python fancy stuff", so that you may learn what is the Pythonic way to do things. Unless, of course, you want to use Python once in your lifetime, which is on this task.

Comment: Can you show us what the output list should look like in this case, expressed in terms of some functions `A`, `B`, and `C`, and `dataset2d`?

Comment: @Eric Okay, I updated the answer to include the output.

Comment: Why are you storing integers as strings? Python sequences do not have to be homogenous

Comment: I did that because its in a file, and I'm just reading the file contents as is in a 2D list using line.strip() in a loop. I didn't know Python sequences do not have to be homogenous. I'll see if I can copy first column of the file as string and rest as integers.

Comment: You might want to undo one of my earlier edits where I converted the file format into python lists if the data is coming from files...

Comment: partition2d[1:] skips the first row, not the first column since its 2D list. @Eric I didn't edit your answer

Comment: No, but [I edited your question](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/18889810/6)

Comment: What is the formula used to produce your output? The first and second column of your array for partition A is the same (both `(0, 2, 1)`) but your result is different (`0.842322` and `0.94322`)).'

Comment: what do you mean by "declare the size"?

Comment: never mind, solved that problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Numpy](http://www.numpy.org) (I hope this is not fancy for you):

```
import numpy
dataset2D = [ [6, 4], [0, 0, 0, 1], [1, 0, 2, 0], [2, 2, 0, 1], [1, 1, 1, 0], [0, 0, 1, 1], [1, 0, 2, 1] ]
dataset2D_size = dataset2D[0]
dataset2D = numpy.array(dataset2D)
partition2D = [ ['A', '1', '2', '4'], ['B', '3', '5'], ['C', '6'] ]

for partition in partition2D:
    label = partition[0]

    row_indices = [int(i) for i in partition[1:]]

    # Take the specified rows
    rows = dataset2D[row_indices]

    # Iterate the columns (this is the power of Python!)
    for column in zip(*rows):
        # Now, column will contain one column of data from specified row indices
        print column, # Apply your formula here
    print
```

or **if you don't want to install Numpy**, here is what you can do (this is what you want, actually):

```
dataset2D = [ [6, 4], [0, 0, 0, 1], [1, 0, 2, 0], [2, 2, 0, 1], [1, 1, 1, 0], [0, 0, 1, 1], [1, 0, 2, 1] ]
partition2D = [ ['A', '1', '2', '4'], ['B', '3', '5'], ['C', '6'] ]

dataset2D_size = dataset2D[0]

for partition in partition2D:
    label = partition[0]

    row_indices = [int(i) for i in partition[1:]]

    rows = [dataset2D[row_idx] for row_idx in row_indices]

    for column in zip(*rows):
        print column,
    print
```

both will print:

```
(0, 1, 1) (0, 0, 1) (0, 2, 1) (1, 0, 0)
(2, 0) (2, 0) (0, 1) (1, 1)
(1,) (0,) (2,) (1,)
```

**Explanation of second code (without Numpy)**:

```
[dataset2D[row_idx] for row_idx in row_indices]
```

This is basically you take each row (`dataset2D[row_idx]`) and collate them together as a list. So the result of this expression is a list of lists (which comes from the specified row indices)

```
for column in zip(*rows):
```

Then `zip(*rows)` will **iterate column-wise** (the one you want). This works by taking the first element of each row, then combine them together to form a [tuple](http://docs.python.org/release/1.5.1p1/tut/tuples.html). In each iteration, the result is stored in variable `column`.

Then inside the `for column in zip(*rows):` you already have your intended column-wise iterated elements from specified rows!

To apply your formula, just change the `print column,` into the stuff you wanna do. For example I modify the code to include row and column number:

```
print 'Processing partition %s' % label
for (col_num, column) in enumerate(zip(*rows)):
    print 'Column number: %d' % col_num
    for (row_num, element) in enumerate(column):
        print '[%d,%d]: %d' % (row_indices[row_num], col_num, element)
```

which will result in:

```
Processing partition A
Column number: 0
[1,0]: 0
[2,0]: 1
[4,0]: 1
Column number: 1
[1,1]: 0
[2,1]: 0
[4,1]: 1
Column number: 2
[1,2]: 0
[2,2]: 2
[4,2]: 1
Column number: 3
[1,3]: 1
[2,3]: 0
[4,3]: 0
Processing partition B
Column number: 0
[3,0]: 2
[5,0]: 0
Column number: 1
[3,1]: 2
[5,1]: 0
Column number: 2
[3,2]: 0
[5,2]: 1
Column number: 3
[3,3]: 1
[5,3]: 1
Processing partition C
Column number: 0
[6,0]: 1
Column number: 1
[6,1]: 0
Column number: 2
[6,3]: 2
Column number: 3
[6,3]: 1
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: This looks good. However dataset2d also has two numbers in the first row-> 6,4 where 6 is number of rows I need to consider, and 4 is number of columns.

Comment: Oh, so 6,4 is also part of the dataset2d? You can just take the second row onwards to a variable to get rid of the first row =)

Comment: `[i-1 for i in partition[1:]]` is undesirable - my understanding is that the op wants `1` to refer to `[0, 0, 0, 1]` (the first non-size entry) which _is_ `dataset2d[1]`

Comment: THis would probably also be easier to read with `rows = [dataset2D[row_idx] for row_idx in row_indices]`, and `elements` renamed to `column`

Comment: Second list is a 2D string. So partition2D = [ ['A', '1', '2', '4'], ['B', '3', '5'], ['C', '6'] ]. I think if we do int(row_indices) it should work though.

Comment: int(row_indices) doesn't work. TypeError: int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'list'

Comment: You must take `row_indices = [int(i) for i in partition[1:]]` instead. That is, you apply `int` function to each element of the list, not directly on the list.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an extensible solution using an iterator:

```
def partitions(data, p):
    for partition in p:
        label = partition[0]
        row_indices = partition[1:]
        rows = [dataset2D[row_idx] for row_idx in row_indices]
        columns = zip(*rows)

        yield label, columns

for label, columns in partitions(dataset2D, partitions2d):
    print "Processing", label
    for column in columns:
        print column
```

Comment: partition2d is a 2D string list.

Comment: partition2d[1:] skips the first row, not the first column since its 2D list.

Answer (score 1):

> partition2d is a string array where I need to skip the first column
>   which has characters like A,B,C.

This is called slicing:

```
 for partitionCol in partitionRow[1:]:
```

the above snippet will skip the first column.

```
 for colDataset in dataset2d:
```

Already does what you want. There is no structure here like in C++ loops. Although you could do stuff in a very Unpythonic way:

```
 i=0
 for i in range(len(dataset2d)):
    print dataset2d[partitionCol][i]  
    i=+1
```

**This is a very bad way of doing stuff.** For arrays and matrices, I suggest you don't re-invent the wheel (that is also Pythonic stuff), **look at `Numpy`**. And especially at:
[numpy.loadtxt](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html)

Comment: indeed. But my point is actually that the OP should use Numpy.

Comment: Sure, I saw your point, but your argument is better heard when the rest of your post is without obvious errors. :-)

Comment: numpy.loadtxt says 'Each row in the text file must have the same number of values.' Unfortunately, the first row in dataset2d just contains two numbers (number of rows and cols) and is different from the rest of the file

Comment: @user2441441, you can skip rows, mainly the header row.

Answer (score 1):

to address your problems:

> What problem I'm facing:
>
> 1. partition2d is a string array where I need to
>    skip the first column which has characters like A,B,C.
> 2. I want to
>    iterate in dataset2d column wise only over the row numbers given in
>    partition2d. So the colDataset should increment only after I'm done
>    with that column.

Problem 1 can be solved using slicing - if you want to iterate on partition2d from the second element only you can to something `for partitionCol in partitionRow[1:]`. This will slice the row starting from the second element to the end.

So something like:

```
 for partitionRow in partition2d:
        for partitionCol in partitionRow[1:]:
                for colDataset in dataset2d:
                    print dataset2d[partitionCol][colDataset]
```

Problem 2 I didn't understand what you want :)

Answer (score 1):

Setup:

```
d = [[6,4],[0,0,0,1],[1,0,2,0],[2,2,0,1],[1,1,1,0],[0,0,1,1],[1,0,2,1]]
s = [['A',1,2,4],['B',3,5],['C',6]]
```

The results are put into a list l

```
l = []
for r in s: #go over each [character,index0,index1,...]
    new_r = [r[0]] #create a new list to values given by indexN. Add in the character by default
    for i,c in enumerate(r[1:]): #go over each indexN. Using enumerate to keep track of what N is. 
        new_r.append(d[c][i]) #i is now the N in indexN. c is the column.
    l.append(new_r) #add that new list to l
```

Resulting in

```
>>> l
[['A', 0, 0, 1], ['B', 2, 0], ['C', 1]]
```

The execution of the first iteration would look like:

```
for r in s:
    #-> r = ['A',1,2,4]

    new_r = [r[0]] #= ['A']

    for i,c in enumerate([r[1:] = [1,2,4])
            #-> i = 0, c = 1
                new_r.append(d[1][i])
            #-> i = 1, c = 2
                #...
```

Comment: this indeed very legal Python Syntax, but it has a C++ way of doing stuff. It will also be very slow for large matrices, because of your append. List comprehension would be more appropriate, or generators. Or like I said, and so did justhalf. Numpy is the way!

Comment: Thanks @Oz123. I added my answer with the non-Numpy Pythonic way to do stuff. =)

Comment: @Oz123 You're right, this can easily be turned into a list comprehension (or generator) however it's easier to understand in a non-flattened form :)